# Swift AVAudioPlayer Bluetooth Sound Delay

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, delay, avaudioplayer

When utilizing the AVAudioPlayer for playback, I am experiencing a 1 to 3 second delay when playing the audio over bluetooth.  This delay is not present when disconnected from bluetooth and not present when speakers are connected directly to the device using an audio jack.

I have tried placing the AVAudioPlayer on it's own queue, I have also tried playing 1 second of pure silence before playing the actual audio:

```
extension AVAudioPlayer {

    func prepareIntroToPlay() {
        prepareToPlay()
        volume = 0
        play()
        stop()
        prepareToPlay()
    }
}
```

I have also made my AVAudioPlayer a managing singleton, that plays the one second of silence on it's own queue. All this preperation still does not remove the AVAudioPlayer delay over Bluetooth.

I shouldn't really use the word "delay".  If you had an AudioFile with a recording of "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10"; when connected to Bluetooth you would hear "4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10".

I have found this open radar:  http://www.openradar.me/41482862 pertaining to the issue, but I am wondering if there is any work-around for this issue?

I am in need of my AVAudioPlayer to mix with other sounds, because I do have an MPMusicPlayerController that plays music as well (this seems unaffected by bluetooth audio, works fine).

**Audio Player Session Config:**

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try session.setCategory(.playback, options: .mixWithOthers)
try session.setActive(true, options: [])
```

Comment: How have you configured your AVAudioSession? Have you previously activated it, or are you relying on AVAudioPlayer to do so for you?

Comment: Updated my question with the AVAudioPlayer Config.  

My use case is that the user taps on a TableViewCell.  The cell is in the selected state, at this time I ask the AVAudioPlayer to prepareToPlay (and call the session code referenced above that I added to my question).  When the user taps the play button I call play on the AVAudioPlayer.

Comment: Calling `prepareToPlay` immediately before calling `play` doesn't help anything. The point of `prepareToPlay` is to preload everything needed for playback. You want to prepareToPlay early, not just-in-time.

Comment: I thought initially that could be the issue, however the AVAudioPlayer prepare to play returns a boolean value indicating if it is prepared to play.  I've logged it over countless sessions with it always being prepared to play the content (which at the most could be 15 seconds of .caf audio).  If it were not prepared to play this bluetooth delay would also persist on the device speakers as well, and not just over bluetooth.

Comment: It is playing (if it weren't, you wouldn't lose the initial part of the audio). The trick is getting the A2DP session active. Playing silence, or even very low volume audio does not always activate the session. I never use AVAudioPlayer; I always build this with AVAudioEngine and AVAudioPlayerNode (or occasionally AVPlayer), so I'm just thinking through how to make AVAudioPlayer behave more like the others. (You may also try rewriting this on AVPlayer or AVAudioEngine.) Also check if it goes away if another process is playing audio already (so the A2DP session is active).

Comment: Be very aware that there are two audio modes in Bluetooth: HFP and A2DP. HFP is used by phone calls (or any time the microphone is enabled). It has really bad audio; you should be able to hear the difference; it's like music over a phone line. A2DP is "music" audio and does not support a microphone. Switching between them can cause you to lose audio. If you ever see "allowBluetooth" know that is actually "prefer HFP." The A2DP setting is called "allowBluetoothA2DP"

Comment: This is really good to know.  I have never built from AVAudioEngine before (or AVAudioPlayerNode/AVPlayer).  You seem to have a really high level of understanding of how these all work.  I would believe that what I am hearing from my playback is in A2DP.  If I play the first recording over bluetooth I get lost audio, where-as switching to another audio file presents with no lost audio.  On another case, if I play one with lost audio, and wait 10 mins (or background the app) I again get lost audio over bluetooth.  If I play the recordings one after another, only the first does this.

Comment: Yeah, your A2DP sessions are almost cerrtainly timing out. That's common with Bluetooth audio (it's often something decided by the Bluetooth device, not the phone or software). It takes time to reestablish them. You'll see this sometimes when you switch to Bluetooth headphones, and immediately start typing on an iPhone. The first several keyboard clicks are often lost. Some of this is not easily fixable by software without some control over the device's firmware. Sometimes the solution is to find a way to keep playing some audio.

Comment: (I build Bluetooth headphones for a living; this stuff comes up. Unfortunately there are many things about Bluetooth that are unfixable due to the protocol itself. Extensive experimentation is often required, but there aren't always good answers.)

Comment: The only thing that drives me crazy is wondering why MPMusicPlayerController seems unaffected.  The only thing that I can think of, is that it's session is always active and ready, where-as AVAudioPlayer isn't?